# Interview with Bjarne Stroustrup - abstraction and hand-crafted code

Tags: c++

I have read an [interview](http://electronicdesign.com/dev-tools/interview-bjarne-stroustrup-discusses-c) with Bjarne Stroustrup on C++ and its design. I was confused by the terminology he used there so I was hoping to get some of such moments clarified.

> I documented my design aims and the constraints on the design in my book “The Design and Implementation of C++” and in my two History of Programming Languages conference papers, but briefly, I aim for
>
> - zero overhead compared to hand-crafted code when using abstractions,
> - a machine model very similar to that of C,
> - an extremely flexible set of abstraction mechanism, and
> - static type safety.

1. What does "hand-crafted code" mean in this case?.. Does Stroustrup
   mean some hand-crafted tool for an abstraction concept a programer
   could create?
2. What does "machine model" mean in this case? A way a language interact with hardware?

I took a look on the book he mentioned (which is actually “The Design and **Evolution** of C++”, I believe) but I'm still not really sure. These two terms are also not googled very well.

Comment: Might be better suited for the stackExchange programmer site, overflow relates specifically *code* related problems. Good question though hopefully can still be answered here.

Comment: @Gmercer015 Oops. OK, sorry, I didn't know that.

Comment: @remyabel I've read this one. I do understand the meaning of "hand-crafted" by iteslf, what I do not understand is what is hand-crafted here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Machine model" means the ways in which the computer manifests itself in the language. So for example, C and C++ treat bytes, memory locations, pointers, integer types in more or less the same ways.

"Hand-crafted" here means equivalent code that does not use the abstraction provided in C++, and is written efficiently in C or assembly (or C++, just excluding that abstraction). This is an "aim", not a "constraint" -- C++ does not precisely achieve it in all cases.

So just as an example, `vector<int>` does not always achieve exactly the same performance as a similar resizable array written using `malloc` and `free`, because that code could (and naturally would) use `realloc` to resize the storage when necessary. `realloc` doesn't very often save you any time, but when it does it saves a chunk. `vector` cannot do that, because the allocator interface has nothing equivalent to `realloc`, and hence has introduced a small overhead. But `vector` has roughly the same performance, almost all of the time, so the aim of zero-overhead is nearly met.

For another example: with a decent C++ compiler in release mode, writing `myvector_of_int[3]` genuinely has zero overhead compared with writing `my_int_pointer[3]`. It may not be immediately obvious why accessing a data member of a local variable (the data pointer stored in `myvector_of_int`) has no overhead compared with accessing a local variable of pointer type (`my_int_pointer`), but it needn't cost anything extra.

Comment: So you're saying Bjarne aims to **not** use the abstraction provided by c++?

Comment: No, I'm saying that he aims for there to be zero overhead if you do use the abstraction. Overhead compared with "hand-crafted" code, that is to say code that does the same thing as the abstraction-using code does, but explicitly in C instead of letting the C++ compiler/libraries do it for you.

Comment: Would the «machine model» include, for instance, POSIX multythreading implementation? Like, fork() in C and C++ should both proceed in a same way.

Comment: @kazarey: yes, although multi-threading wasn't part of either standard until the most recent versions (2011) and `fork()` still isn't part of either. The most important part of any multi-threading model are the definitions of a thread of execution and of a data race (and how to prevent one), which is all basically the same in both. Details like the name of the function used to start a new thread are not part of the "machine model".

Answer (score 6):

By "hand-crafted" code, Stroustrup means a hand-written implementation of the abstraction; for example, a hand-crafted `for` loop would be N copies of the loop body.  (See [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) for a non-trivial implementation.)

And by "machine model", Stroustrup means the compiler's view of the machine.  For example, C and C++ provide roughly equivalent views of bytes, memory locations, memory access ordering, and so forth; Fortran, by contrast, doesn't have any concept of "bytes", and memory locations (or array accessing, for that matter) doesn't correspond well to the C/C++ view at all.

Comment: "a hand-crafted for loop would be N copies of the loop body" -- or depending how you look at it, a hand-crafted `for` loop would involve an `if` and a `goto` in C or C++, or a conditional branch in assembly. It's a question of what you consider the important property of the abstraction to be, and that might vary by context.